# How to run python/Tkinter in a VNC conected to a EC2 instance

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, tkinter, amazon-ec2, vnc

I was able to connect to the EC2 instance through TigerVNC, but when running python applications that have Tkinter I get the following error:

```
Tkinter: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment
```

Then I ran the following command:

```
export DISPLAY=:1
```

So I get the following error when running python code:

```
Couldn't connect to display ":1"
```

Any suggestion to solve this?

Comment: [See this answer, it should be simliar to your issue](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/106848/134290)

Comment: Passing `ip_address:1` to TigarVNC just means that VNC connects on port 5901.  It has nothing to do with X.  Are you running these Tkinter application on your remote instance?  That should be `DISPLAY=:0`.

Comment: Yes, I'm running in my remote instance connected by TigerVNC, but i'm receiving the same error: Coudn't connect to display ":0"... I've also tried in other ways like: 127.0.0.1:0 or public_ip_adress:0, but it didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

I created a new EC2 instance and when installing lxde I chose gdm3 as the default display manager option.. so I was able to run xcalc with DISPLAY=:1.0.. But when running the application that contained Tkinter I had the same problem.. The solution was the following command:

```
export DISPLAY=:1.0; xhost +
```

So xhost helps you use the computing power of another machine like an EC2 instance to run a graph and display it on the client screen.